# Emscripten: Customize the generated js so it loads the .wasm file in a custom way

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

By compiling with the following options,

`emcc -s WASM=1 main.cpp -o index.js`

emscripten generates an `index.wasm`, and a js wrapper `index.js`.
The js wrapper loads the `.wasm` file located in the same directory, using `XMLHttpRequest` when it's running in a browser.

So what should I do if I need to load of the `.wasm` file manually? The loading part seems hard-coded in the wrapper.

Here are some circumstances where I need this:

- I need to serve the `.wasm` file from another url (for example from CDN).
- The url to download the `.wasm` file is dynamically generated.
- The code is running in a sandbox where `XMLHttpRequest` is not allowed, there is only an API like `getMyData('some_file')`.
- I need to embed all the files as base64 string.

I know I could generate the `.wasm` file only, by

`emcc -s WASM=1 main.cpp -o index.wasm`

But then I loses the wrapper, which is not trivial when using some emscripten APIs like SDL and GLES.

Comment: What is the oldest browser you're supporting? The XHR restriction can be bypassed if your browsers support it

Comment: @AnthumChris It's not a typical browser, it is a sandbox environment where the your files can only be loaded with give APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFIK, the JS wrapper calls fetch() and not XHR.  If available, you could use a Service Worker to intercept that request and return whatever you'd like.

You could also modify the Emscripten source (I have v1.39.13) to rewrite the default loading behavior.  In file `$EMSDK/upstream/emscripten/src/preamble.js`, modify functions [`getBinaryPromise()`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/1.39.13/src/preamble.js#L860) and [`getBinary()`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/1.39.13/src/preamble.js#L833) to your liking, then build with `emcc` to have your custom loading behavior in the WASM JS wrapper.

Comment: I have 1.39.13 running on macOS, and it uses XHR in the wrapper for Web environment.

Comment: (After formatting and reading the code again...) The wrapper first try to load the `.wasm` file with `fetch` and if it fails it calls `readBinary` which uses XHR. The part for that is in https://pastebin.com/B4FJ2PSs

Comment: OK, I will accept this answer for now because there doesn't seem to be any decent solution for now.